# Kusto: extract unique words in text

Tags: regex, azure, azure-data-explorer

is it possible extract unique word from column with Kusto?

Example text: an example text, an orange, text bold
Get only words: an, example, text, orange, bold

I'm trying with this regex:

> mytable | extend ff = extract_all(@'(\w+\b)(?!.*\1\b)', info));

Comment: I don't know your regex tool at all, but your current pattern is working [in this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/x7D9Ck/1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try this, using `set_union()` on top of the output of `extract_all()`:

```
print input = "an example text, an orange, text bold Get only words: an, example, text, orange, bold"
| extend unique_words = set_union(dynamic(null), extract_all(@"(\w+)", input))
```

| input | unique_words |
| --- | --- |
| an example text, an orange, text bold Get only words: an, example, text, orange, bold | [ "an", "example", "text", "orange", "bold", "Get", "only", "words" ] |

Comment: Thanks, although the performance on a big table is too slow, is there any other way?

Comment: if this is a query you run frequently, you can consider calculating the unique words once at ingestion time, using an [update policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/updatepolicy)